# Fixed Point Iteration Scheme

Tags: roots, fixed-point-theorems

I have been asked to "Find a fixed point iteration scheme for minimising $f(x) = e^{cos (x)}$".

Does anybody know what a fixed point iteration scheme actually is?  I know it's not Fixed Point Iteration or Newton-Raphson, since I am then asked to solve using both of these in the next two parts.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Perhaps they are asking you to put it into a form where fixed point iteration may be applied to find the minima?

Comment: I found out today - 'apparently' a scheme is the iteration.  So I was been asked to convert the equation to something I could iterate over, then iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

As the original does not converge, it needs to be transformed to an equivalent equation that does.
Obviously one may apply $ln$ and then $arccos$ to both sides, and that equality converges.
But one may take another approach, and after applying $ln$ to both sides, implement a variable $y = cos(x)$, and get a convergent equality for $y$. While this does not converge any faster, in some cases variable substitution can achive such an effect - see [my analysis in my article](https://medium.com/@davidlaczkoo/fixed-point-iteration-rediscovered-e3feeb10b06a) of the topic.